# "of stealing" vs. "to steal"

Tags: gerunds

i just read a comment on Facebook:

> Future grandpa will have more chances of stealing your girlfriend.

Can I use this sentence by another way:

> Future grandpa will have more chances to steal your girlfriend.

Nouns in English really make me confused.

Comment: chance of {something},  chance to {do something}.   *I studied hard, so I have a good chance of passing the exam* and *You can take this test  up to three times. You have three chances to pass it.*

Answer (score 3):

They are different in meanings. You use "to infinitive" when it refers to **an occasion that allows something to be done**. You use "of-phrase" when it implies **a level of possibility that something will happen.** So

> will have chances to steal (=will have an occasion to allow him stealing.. "
>
> will have chances of stealing(=there will be a possibility that he will steal...)

([Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/chance))

Comment: +1 for the distinction, but fixing a typo (to stealing)

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo and "changes" too, thanks.

Comment: Note that this is a lexical property of the word "chance", not a general comment about English grammar.